# how to configure gradle in androidstudio and my android project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

this is my default gradle version.[image]

then this is my config in my project ,like this[image]

however,when i set the gradle version in project structure,like this,my studio show a progress till now.[image]

i don't know whether is my config wrong,or other reason.Can any one tell me how to config the gradle? thanks!

Comment: With installed gradle I remember we need to set GRADLE_HOME environment variable. Have you done that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck Offline work on Global Grade settings.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidStudio came with gradle-wrapper AKA ./gradlw so ideally you don't really need to install gradle on the machine.
Check the network settings if it takes too long for gradle to download all the dependencies.
And don't check offline mode :)